# Print com contador em python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando criar um RPG de texto em python, então para facilitar a escrita de cada episódio do jogo, resolvi criar uma declaração de um texto:

```
def episódios():
episódio = '{:^50}'.format(f'EPISÓDIO **{ESSE AQUI}**')
linha = '=' * 50
for l in linha:
    sys.stdout.write(l)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.02)
print('\n')
for l in episódio:
    sys.stdout.write(l)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.07)
print('\n')
for l in linha:
    sys.stdout.write(l)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
print('\n')
```

Gostaria de saber se eu conseguiria criar um contador dentro das chaves que escrevi "ESTE AQUI", para que cada vez que eu chamasse a declaração ele aumentasse em ordem crescente de 1 em 1.

Exemplo:
Chamei a primeira vez:
episódios()
ele escreve na tela 'Episódio 1'
e na próxima chamada 'Episódio 2'
e assim sucessivamente

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Basta você criar uma variável auxiliar para realizar a contagem e incrementá-la dentro da sua função, para que a contagem aumente a cada chamada. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
contador = 0

def obter_episodio():
    global contador

    contador += 1
    return f"EPISÓDIO {contador}"

print(obter_episodio()) # EPISÓDIO 1
print(obter_episodio()) # EPISÓDIO 2
print(obter_episodio()) # EPISÓDIO 3
```